# Logging rssh/chroot SFTP users

Tags: centos, logging, sftp, chroot, syslogd

I'm trying to log activity (uploads, downloads, renames, deletes) for SFTP users.
If I SFTP with a normal user, it logs to `/var/log/secure`.
If I SFTP with a rssh user, it logs that they connected, but nothing else.

In **/var/log/messages** it shows:

> rssh[8287]: setting log facility to LOG_USER
>   rssh[8287]: allowing scp to all users
>   rssh[8287]: allowing sftp to all users
>   rssh[8287]: allowing rsync to all users
>   rssh[8287]: setting umask to 022
>   rssh[8287]: chrooting all users to /home/data
>   rssh[8287]: chroot cmd line: /usr/local/libexec/rssh_chroot_helper 2 "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -f AUTHPRIV -l VERBOSE"
>   rssh_chroot_helper[8287]: new session for USERNAME, UID=721
>   rssh_chroot_helper[8287]: user's home dir is /home/data/home/USERNAME
>   rssh_chroot_helper[8287]: chrooted to /home/data
>   rssh_chroot_helper[8287]: changing working directory to /home/USERNAME (inside jail)

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV LogLevel DEBUG Subsystem       sftp   
/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -f AUTHPRIV -l VERBOSE
```

**/etc/syslog.conf**

```
authpriv.*                                             
/var/log/secure
```

I've tried to find a solution online, but nothing seems to work. I tried doing the following with a link set to `/dev/log` and `/var/log/secure`, but neither worked.

**/etc/sysconfig/syslog**

```
SYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-m 0 -a /home/data/home/USERNAME/dev/log"
```